# Remote/External Infinispan for Keycloak 20.0.5 (Quarkus distribution)

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, infinispan

I'm trying to configure the external Infinispan cluster for the Keycloak cluster with Keycloak Quarkus distribution. Unfortunately, I can't configure that. Because I don't find exact documentation about the configuration remote/external Infinispan cluster for Keycloak Quarkus. I would be happy if someone helps me with that.

I can't find exact documentation about that. But, when I look at documentations about that, I just see some documentations in WildFly distributions.